# Jedis as message queue performance

Tags: java, performance, redis, jedis

I am using the Java library Jedis ontop of a Redis queue which I am using as a producer/consumer queue. It was easy to set up and is working nicely.

Consumer code below

```
List<String> messages = jedis.blpop(0, redisQueueName);
String message = messages.get(1);
//do some stuff
```

I'm looking to see if I can speed up performance as I have a large amount of items sitting in the Redis queue waiting to be picked up. I've timed my custom processing code and it does not take too long (20000 nano seconds).

Would best practice be to pull multiple items from Redis at once and process them in a batch? Or am I better looking at tuning the Redis server for better performance?

Comment: Your issue might indeed be at IO with Redis than at processing - I would grab them in batches; without any sort of transaction you can lose messages anyway; the fact that you're using Redis suggests that this isn't a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes pulling in batch is indeed the best practice. You will be avoiding network round trip.

One more thing is to trim the queue if it goes beyond certain range as the queue grows rapidly and you want to have the control over the queue size (memory size). Sometimes you may not need to perform each and every entry in the queue instead you may skip few as the queue size grows big.

If you want to retain first entered elements, ie., 
For retaining first 100 elements alone

```
Ltrim queue 0 100
```

To retain last 100 elements you can do

```
Ltrim queue -1 100
```

Hope this helps